# JSTL nested forEach Lists throwing error

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am trying use JSTL on an old project where I have to use nested `forEach`.

My requirement is for example to iterate through a countries list, where each country will have a `StateList` which will contain State details.

```
<c:forEach items="${countryList}" var="country"> 
  <c:out value="${country.name}" escapeXml="true" /> 
    <c:forEach items="${country.StateList}" var="state"> 
         <c:out value="${state.name}" escapeXml="true" />   
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

When I try these I am getting error.

```
An error occurred while evaluating custom action attribute "items" with value "${country.StateList}": Unable to find a value for "StateList" in object of class "com.pack.Country" using operator "." (null)
```

What I am doing wrong? Is there a alternate method to do the same without using scriplets?

Issue Solved : The problem was that i used StateList instead of stateList as list name in class. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `countryList` has `StateList` as a member? Tell us what are the members of class `com.pack.Country`?

Comment: Yes it is having StateList. Rest all the members are Strings.

Comment: Please add the source for the 'Country' class.

Comment: May be problem with *case* , Use exact property name.

Comment: Is getter, setter for the `StateList` is there? You need to give the name according to Java Bean naming conventions like `stateList`

Comment: The Countries and States where hypothical to mach my projects problem. I will paste the actual code. How can i edit my question?

Comment: @vikka There is an *edit* link below the question. Use that.

Comment: Thanks guys, The issue was silly. I was using StateList as the name in the Country Class. Now i made it to stateList it worked like expected.   Thanks a Lot for your Time and Efforts.

Comment: [click here to edit question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21425965/edit)